# ExpandableListView expanding over other layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Header text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:padding="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/headerBackground"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listview_items"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the expandable listview has a long list of items, it `expands` over the bottom layout (the buttons layout).

Is there a way to tell the listview to expand up to where the bottom layout starts?

Comment: you have made height to match_parent try wrap_content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made some changes in your XML File.What I did is make your Button Layout `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and make your details layout as `android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"`.Hope it will solve your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Header text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/headerBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Back"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Next"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Can you check whether your button layout height is match_parent, If yes make it to wrap_content or you can simply use my code. Its your example code only with some modification.

Comment: I changed it to wrap_content. But now the top layout moves down and starts from the middle. When I expand the listview, the layout moves up.

Comment: Ok. Changed the top layout height to match_parent and it works now.